# Perfomance postgresql 9.1.9/9.3.6 vs 9.4.1

Tags: performance, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am comparing 9.1.9/9.3.6 and 9.4.1. I think that perfomance of 9.4.1 should be better or at least not worse.
But I have an issue here.
I have installed both db on the same machine, restored the same dump, used ANALYZE and I have 2 results, where I see that for some reason 9.1.9 works faster - 118ms vs 452ms.
I checked the same sql query with EXPLAIN ANALYZE (with the same work_mem =8MB and shared_buffers = 128MB).

1) 9.1.9

```
QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=6929.93..6929.94 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=99.175..99.178 rows=25 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=6929.93..6929.94 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=99.175..99.175 rows=25 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (CASE WHEN (p.f_without_price = 1) THEN 0::double precision ELSE p1.price END)
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
         ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=133.65..6929.92 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.345..97.884 rows=4876 loops=1)
               Join Filter: ((p2.price < p1.price) OR ((p2.price = p1.price) AND (p2.id < p1.id)))
               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=90.19..6882.40 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.344..64.038 rows=4891 loops=1)
                     Filter: (((p.f_without_price = 1) OR (p1.price <> 0::double precision)) AND (CASE WHEN (p.f_without_price = 1) THEN 0::double precision ELSE p1.price END <> 0::double precision))
                     ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=46.75..6834.91 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.344..23.213 rows=4889 loops=1)
                           Join Filter: (p.f_assignable = 0)
                           Filter: (((p.f_assignable = 1) AND (pc.product_id IS NOT NULL)) OR ((p.f_assignable = 0) AND (pch.product_id IS NULL)))
                           ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=46.75..6822.71 rows=2 width=58) (actual time=0.344..16.257 rows=4907 loops=1)
                                 Join Filter: (p.f_assignable = 1)
                                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=46.75..6809.23 rows=2 width=54) (actual time=0.343..8.678 rows=4907 loops=1)
                                       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..24.84 rows=1 width=58) (actual time=0.017..0.052 rows=2 loops=1)
                                             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..16.55 rows=1 width=54) (actual time=0.013..0.035 rows=3 loops=1)
                                                   Join Filter: (cs.supplier_id = grps.supplier_id)
                                                   ->  Index Scan using cs_aggregated_groups_pkey on cs_aggregated_groups grps  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=50) (actual time=0.006..0.008 rows=3 loops=1)
                                                         Index Cond: (customer_id = 1388)
                                                   ->  Index Scan using index_15 on cs_groups cs  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.007 rows=3 loops=3)
                                                         Index Cond: (customer_id = 1388)
                                                         Filter: (f_primary_group = 1)
                                             ->  Index Scan using index_26 on supplier s  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=3)
                                                   Index Cond: (id = cs.supplier_id)
                                                   Filter: ((f_active = 1) AND (f_deleted = 0))
                                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on product p  (cost=46.75..6754.19 rows=2416 width=12) (actual time=0.401..3.683 rows=2454 loops=2)
                                             Recheck Cond: (supplier_id = s.id)
                                             Filter: ((f_available = 1) AND (f_active = 1) AND (f_deleted = 0) AND ((f_assignable = 1) OR (f_assignable = 0)))
                                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_57  (cost=0.00..46.41 rows=2416 width=0) (actual time=0.320..0.320 rows=3550 loops=2)
                                                   Index Cond: (supplier_id = s.id)
                                 ->  Index Scan using index_49 on product_customer pc  (cost=0.00..6.72 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=4907)
                                       Index Cond: ((product_id = p.id) AND (customer_id = 1388) AND (customer_id = cs.customer_id))
                           ->  Index Scan using index_63 on product_customer_hidden pch  (cost=0.00..6.08 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=4907)
                                 Index Cond: ((product_id = p.id) AND (customer_id = 1388) AND (customer_id = cs.customer_id))
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on price p1  (cost=43.44..47.46 rows=1 width=27) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=4889)
                           Recheck Cond: ((product_id = p.id) AND ((group_id)::text = ANY ((grps.grp_ids)::text[])) AND (amount = 1))
                           Filter: (f_valid = 1)
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on price_product_id_group_id_amount_type_id_valid_from_valid_t_key  (cost=0.00..43.44 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=4889)
                                 Index Cond: ((product_id = p.id) AND ((group_id)::text = ANY ((grps.grp_ids)::text[])) AND (amount = 1))
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on price p2  (cost=43.47..47.48 rows=1 width=27) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=4891)
                     Recheck Cond: ((product_id = p1.product_id) AND ((group_id)::text = ANY ((grps.grp_ids)::text[])) AND (amount = 1) AND (amount = p1.amount))
                     Filter: (f_valid = 1)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on price_product_id_group_id_amount_type_id_valid_from_valid_t_key  (cost=0.00..43.47 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=4891)
                           Index Cond: ((product_id = p1.product_id) AND ((group_id)::text = ANY ((grps.grp_ids)::text[])) AND (amount = 1) AND (amount = p1.amount))
 Total runtime: 99.297 ms
(45 rows)
```

2) 9.4.1

```
QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=503.71..503.72 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=416.762..416.764 rows=25 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=503.71..503.72 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=416.734..416.734 rows=25 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (CASE WHEN (p.f_without_price = 1) THEN 0::double precision ELSE p1.price END)
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
         ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=37.73..503.70 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.736..415.337 rows=4876 loops=1)
               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=37.16..497.90 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.697..379.099 rows=4891 loops=1)
                     Join Filter: ((p1.group_id)::text = ANY ((grps.grp_ids)::text[]))
                     Rows Removed by Join Filter: 485609
                     Filter: (((p.f_without_price = 1) OR (p1.price <> 0::double precision)) AND (CASE WHEN (p.f_without_price = 1) THEN 0::double precision ELSE p1.price END <> 0::double precision))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 13
                     ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=36.61..487.14 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.619..24.466 rows=4889 loops=1)
                           Join Filter: ((p.f_assignable = 0) AND (pch.customer_id = cs.customer_id))
                           Filter: (((p.f_assignable = 1) AND (pc.product_id IS NOT NULL)) OR ((p.f_assignable = 0) AND (pch.product_id IS NULL)))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 18
                           ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=36.33..486.50 rows=2 width=58) (actual time=0.595..17.019 rows=4907 loops=1)
                                 Join Filter: ((p.f_assignable = 1) AND (pc.customer_id = cs.customer_id))
                                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=36.03..485.82 rows=2 width=54) (actual time=0.573..8.876 rows=4907 loops=1)
                                       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..18.42 rows=1 width=58) (actual time=0.101..0.122 rows=2 loops=1)
                                             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..16.49 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.078..0.091 rows=2 loops=1)
                                                   ->  Index Scan using index_15 on cs_groups cs  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.020..0.024 rows=3 loops=1)
                                                         Index Cond: (customer_id = 1388)
                                                         Filter: (f_primary_group = 1)
                                                   ->  Index Scan using index_26 on supplier s  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=1 loops=3)
                                                         Index Cond: (id = cs.supplier_id)
                                                         Filter: ((f_active = 1) AND (f_deleted = 0))
                                                         Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                                             ->  Index Scan using cs_aggregated_groups_pkey on cs_aggregated_groups grps  (cost=0.28..1.92 rows=1 width=50) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=2)
                                                   Index Cond: ((customer_id = 1388) AND (supplier_id = s.id))
                                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on product p  (cost=35.32..454.81 rows=1259 width=12) (actual time=0.456..3.332 rows=2454 loops=2)
                                             Recheck Cond: (supplier_id = s.id)
                                             Filter: ((f_available = 1) AND (f_active = 1) AND (f_deleted = 0))
                                             Rows Removed by Filter: 1096
                                             Heap Blocks: exact=2866
                                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_57  (cost=0.00..35.01 rows=2274 width=0) (actual time=0.300..0.300 rows=3550 loops=2)
                                                   Index Cond: (supplier_id = s.id)
                                 ->  Index Only Scan using index_49 on product_customer pc  (cost=0.29..0.33 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=4907)
                                       Index Cond: ((product_id = p.id) AND (customer_id = 1388))
                                       Heap Fetches: 0
                           ->  Index Only Scan using index_63 on product_customer_hidden pch  (cost=0.28..0.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=4907)
                                 Index Cond: ((product_id = p.id) AND (customer_id = 1388))
                                 Heap Fetches: 0
                     ->  Index Scan using price_product_id_group_id_amount_type_id_valid_from_valid_t_key on price p1  (cost=0.56..5.36 rows=166 width=27) (actual time=0.006..0.056 rows=100 loops=4889)
                           Index Cond: ((product_id = p.id) AND (amount = 1))
                           Filter: (f_valid = 1)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 0
               ->  Index Scan using price_product_id_group_id_amount_type_id_valid_from_valid_t_key on price p2  (cost=0.56..5.79 rows=1 width=27) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=4891)
                     Index Cond: ((product_id = p1.product_id) AND ((group_id)::text = ANY ((grps.grp_ids)::text[])) AND (amount = p1.amount) AND (amount = 1))
                     Filter: ((f_valid = 1) AND ((price < p1.price) OR ((price = p1.price) AND (id < p1.id))))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning time: 2.975 ms
 Execution time: 416.935 ms
(51 rows)
```

3) 9.3.6

```
QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=5705.15..5705.16 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=101.671..101.674 rows=25 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=5705.15..5705.16 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=101.667..101.669 rows=25 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (CASE WHEN (p.f_without_price = 1) THEN 0::double precision ELSE p1.price END)
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
         ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=42.85..5705.14 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.505..100.493 rows=4876 loops=1)
               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=42.29..5662.50 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.502..68.448 rows=4891 loops=1)
                     Filter: (((p.f_without_price = 1) OR (p1.price <> 0::double precision)) AND (CASE WHEN (p.f_without_price = 1) THEN 0::double precision ELSE p1.price END <> 0::double precision))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 13
                     ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=41.72..5612.79 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.499..26.178 rows=4889 loops=1)
                           Join Filter: ((p.f_assignable = 0) AND (pch.customer_id = cs.customer_id))
                           Filter: (((p.f_assignable = 1) AND (pc.product_id IS NOT NULL)) OR ((p.f_assignable = 0) AND (pch.product_id IS NULL)))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 18
                           ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=41.44..5600.55 rows=2 width=58) (actual time=0.497..19.018 rows=4907 loops=1)
                                 Join Filter: ((p.f_assignable = 1) AND (pc.customer_id = cs.customer_id))
                                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=41.15..5587.11 rows=2 width=54) (actual time=0.495..11.064 rows=4907 loops=1)
                                       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..23.07 rows=1 width=58) (actual time=0.024..0.049 rows=2 loops=1)
                                             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..16.49 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.017..0.035 rows=2 loops=1)
                                                   ->  Index Scan using index_15 on cs_groups cs  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.011..0.016 rows=3 loops=1)
                                                         Index Cond: (customer_id = 1388)
                                                         Filter: (f_primary_group = 1)
                                                   ->  Index Scan using index_26 on supplier s  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=3)
                                                         Index Cond: (id = cs.supplier_id)
                                                         Filter: ((f_active = 1) AND (f_deleted = 0))
                                                         Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                                             ->  Index Scan using cs_aggregated_groups_pkey on cs_aggregated_groups grps  (cost=0.28..6.58 rows=1 width=50) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=2)
                                                   Index Cond: ((customer_id = 1388) AND (supplier_id = s.id))
                                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on product p  (cost=40.44..5551.89 rows=1215 width=12) (actual time=0.471..4.755 rows=2454 loops=2)
                                             Recheck Cond: (supplier_id = s.id)
                                             Filter: ((f_available = 1) AND (f_active = 1) AND (f_deleted = 0) AND ((f_assignable = 1) OR (f_assignable = 0)))
                                             Rows Removed by Filter: 1096
                                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_57  (cost=0.00..40.14 rows=2235 width=0) (actual time=0.326..0.326 rows=3550 loops=2)
                                                   Index Cond: (supplier_id = s.id)
                                 ->  Index Only Scan using index_49 on product_customer pc  (cost=0.29..6.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=4907)
                                       Index Cond: ((product_id = p.id) AND (customer_id = 1388))
                                       Heap Fetches: 0
                           ->  Index Only Scan using index_63 on product_customer_hidden pch  (cost=0.28..6.10 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=4907)
                                 Index Cond: ((product_id = p.id) AND (customer_id = 1388))
                                 Heap Fetches: 0
                     ->  Index Scan using price_product_id_group_id_amount_type_id_valid_from_valid_t_key on price p1  (cost=0.56..49.70 rows=1 width=27) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=4889)
                           Index Cond: ((product_id = p.id) AND ((group_id)::text = ANY ((grps.grp_ids)::text[])) AND (amount = 1))
                           Filter: (f_valid = 1)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 0
               ->  Index Scan using price_product_id_group_id_amount_type_id_valid_from_valid_t_key on price p2  (cost=0.56..42.63 rows=1 width=27) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=4891)
                     Index Cond: ((product_id = p1.product_id) AND ((group_id)::text = ANY ((grps.grp_ids)::text[])) AND (amount = p1.amount) AND (amount = 1))
                     Filter: ((f_valid = 1) AND ((price < p1.price) OR ((price = p1.price) AND (id < p1.id))))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Total runtime: 101.835 ms
(47 rows)
```

Sure, perhaps a sql-query is not too good, but I would like to understand why 9.4.1 takes more time x4!
Could you please help me what should I do?

UPD. I installed 9.3.6 and tried the same query. The result is much better than with 9.4.1.

Comment: Please post the whole query and the whole explain.

Comment: You deleted the most import information: The query plan....

Comment: If the plans are too long post both plans to http://explain.depesz.com/ and put links here please. It's not possible to usefully answer this without the plans.

Comment: Sorry, I have added the whole explains. The query is much longer and enough complex...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by @CraigRinger, I put both into explain.depesz.com and looked at them side by side.  The [slow 9.4 query](http://explain.depesz.com/s/uIn0) and the [fast 9.1 query](http://explain.depesz.com/s/UYs).

The plans are basically the same, but two things stand out.  Step 4, the Nested Loop Left Join, takes far longer in 9.4 than in 9.1.  There seems to be a difference between the two, the 9.4 join has an extra filter, `Join Filter: ((p1.group_id)::text = ANY ((grps.grp_ids)::text[]))`.  This may indicate a difference between the two queries.

Then everything is the same until step 17 where everything goes pear shaped for 9.4.  It does an index scan on the price table taking 273 seconds.  9.1 instead does a series of much more efficient Bitmap scans.  Again, there's indications the queries may be different.

I would...

- verify that you're running the same queries
- that both versions of the tables have the same indexes

  - especially on the price table
- run the query a few times to make sure you're not just benchmarking disk caching

Without seeing the query or schema there isn't much else I can do.

Comment: I restored the same dump on all these dbs. I have checked that all tables from the query have the same indexes in all dbs. And I ran the query several times on each db. Btw, I have installed 9.3.6 and tried - it works almost the same as 9.1.9, I have added query plan in the post.

Comment: @Alexander: Did you `analyze` your table after you restored your dump?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, I did. I tried ANALYZE, and VACUUM ANALYZE several times, and ran the query several times after.

Comment: May be 9.4.1. is too sensitive to wrong optimization, and if I want to use it I have to try optimizing of the query at first...